# Combine list of words into one line, then add characters

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, paste

I want to take a file that has a list of words on each line of its own eg.

```
act
bat
cat
dog
eel
```

and put them into one line with comma separated and quoting them. So that it turns out like:

```
'act', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'eel',
```

so, a single quote, then the word, then another single quote, then a comma, then a space. Then output to a new file with a new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{printf ("'\'%s\'', ", $0)}' infile > new_file
'act', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'eel',
```

---

Or to avoid adding an extra comma at the end, use below instead.

```
awk '{printf S"'\''"$0"'\''";S=", "}'
'act', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'eel'
```

---

Or using `paste` without quoting.

```
paste -d, -s infile
act,bat,cat,dog,eel
```

Then quote it with helping `sed`:

```
sed -r "s/(\w+)/'\1'/g" <(paste -d, -s infile)
'act','bat','cat','dog','eel'
```

Comment: Thank you. That awk command will work on most of the files I have. If in the future I have a list file that has over 100,00 words, will it still output onto one line?

Comment: Yes, this will do.

Comment: Can avoid the ugly and errorprone mixed quotes with `awk -vq=\' '{printf q"%s"q", ", $0}'` etc somewhat like Sergiy's perl answer

Answer (score 3):

Short **`printf`** approach:

```
printf "'%s', " $(< file) > output
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` and `tr`:

```
$ sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/', /" file | tr -d '\n'
'act', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'eel',
```

(with no newline at the end of the output)

The `sed` inserts the quotes at the start and end of every line of input (and a comma and space after), while `tr` removes the newlines.

Redirect the output to a file:

```
$ sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/', /" file | tr -d '\n' >newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl approach:

```
$ perl -lne '$sq="\x27";push @a,$sq.$_.$sq;END{ print join( ",",@a) }' input.txt                                                                                                                                                           
'act','bat','cat','dog','eel'
```

- here we use hex value for single quote stored in `sq` variable, and for each line  read from file, we wrap it into single quotes
- each line with single quotes is pushed into `a` array
- once everything is read, join creates a single string of text out of each array item, joined via `,`

Python approach along the same lines:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;sq="\x27";print ",".join([ sq + l.strip() + sq  for l in sys.stdin  ])' < input.txt                                                                                                                                 
'act','bat','cat','dog','eel'
```

- here we redirect input file into the command's `stdin` stream via shell `<` operator
- each line is stripped from newline character `\n` via strip method, quoted via same idea described in Perl approach
- all lines are processed into a list via `[item for item in iterable]` structure (known as list comprehension)
- and finally `",".join()` lets us create a nice string out of all list items