# How to print two consecutive lines separated by one blank line into one line separated by "," (comma)

Tags: text-processing

How can I turn the text

```
St1
number1
1234

St2
number2
456
```

into the following one?

```
st1,number1,1234
st2,number2,1234
```

Comment: In the sample output the second line has `1234` where one would expect `456` - Is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: Will your input file contain commas? In particular, will any single line in your input file contain an end-of-line comma, or two-or-more internal commas?

Answer (score 16):

With the [standard `paste` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
$ paste -sd ',,\n\0' file
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

`s`erially `paste`s the lines of `file` with `,`, `,`, *newline*, *nothing* (not a NUL character as one might think) as `d`elimiters in turn.

Or:

```
$ paste -d ',,\0' - - - - < file
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

`paste`s stdin 4 times with `,`, `,` and *nothing* as `d`elimiters between them.

Comment: thank you very much, I done it

Comment: @aphabeta then you should accept this answer

Answer (score 6):

A Perl way:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print join(",",split(/\n/)) . "\n"; ' file
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

The `-00` turns on perl's "paragraph mode" where "lines" are defined by `\n\n`, so each paragraph is treated as a single "line". The `-n` means "read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line. The script will split the input line on `\n` (newline: end of line character) and then join the resulting elements with a `,`. This is all printed along with a trailing newline.

You could write the same thing like this for clarity:

```
$ perl -00 -ne '@fields=split(/\n/); $out=join(",",@fields); print "$out\n" ' file
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

Or like this, for fun:

```
$ perl -00 -pe '$_=join(",",split(/\n/))."\n";' file
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `awk`:

```
awk '$1=$1' OFS=, RS= file
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

The empty record separator `RS` targets the "blank line", and assigning a field (here: `$1`) makes `awk` reassemble the entire record from the fields using `OFS`.
It assumes `$1` never being 0 or NULL/empty.

Comment: you at least need `{$1=$1; print }` or `{$1=$1};1` incase first field was zero. or force the string conversion by `$1=$1""`.

Comment: I'd add `FS='\n'` to the variable list: not all whitespace should be replaced by commas, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, using any `sed` you could go

```
sed 'N;N;y/\n/,/;n;d' file
```

- With `N;N` you join the `N`ext two lines in the pattern space
- `y/\n/,/` replaces the newlines between the lines with commas (thanks @Stéphane for hinting to use `y` instead of `s`)
- `n` prints the current pattern space while loading the `n`ext line (the empty one), which you then `d`elese

Answer (score 4):

Making use of paragraph mode (-00) in Perl:

```bsh
perl -pals -F'\n' -00e 's/.*/@F/s' -- -\"=, file
```

---

Perl in line by line mode:

```bsh
perl -pe '
  chomp($_.=<>.<>),tr/\n/,/ if/./;
  eof && s/.\K$/\n/;
' file
```

---

POSIXly sed :

```bsh
sed '
  /./{H;$!d;}
  x;y/\n/,/;s/.//
' file
```

---

We can do this using `GNU csplit + xargs paste` pipeline

```bsh
csplit --suppress-matched -sz file '/^$/' '{*}'
printf '%s\n' xx* | xargs -r paste -sd,
```

---

Using `groupby` method from the `itertools` module in Python along with list comprehension:

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it

ofs,(rs,ors) = ",","\n" * 2
g = lambda x: not len(x)
h = lambda x: x.rstrip(rs)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  print(*[ofs.join(igrp) for k,igrp in it.groupby(map(h,f),g) if not k],sep=ors)
' file
```

---

Output:-

```
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

---

Comment: Or `perl -F\\n -als00eprint@F -- -,=,`...

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and no matter what your input values are and no matter how many lines are in each empty-line-separated record:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

Comment: It's more empty-line-separated records, blanks lines that are not empty will not be considered as delimiters with `RS=""`. Note that POSIXly, you need `{$1=$1};1`. I'm not aware of any implementation where the `;` is required, but when [I asked for the requirement to be relaxed](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226), it got [rejected based on input from the gawk maintainer](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226#c2226).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Fair enough, I changed the word blank to empty. I'm aware of that `;` issue and choose to ignore it since, documented or not, an implementation that enforced it would break many existing awk scripts and so it's just never going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all newlines by commas. Empty newlines will create two consecutive commas: re-replace those with a proper newline. Also take care of the dangling comma at the end on the last line.

```
tr '\n' ',' <infile | sed 's/,,/\n/;$s/,$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Probably the most robust solution simulates Perl's `-00` paragraph mode:

```perl
raku -e '.put for lines.join("\n").split(/\n**2..*/).map(*.trans: "\n" => ",");'
```

Sample Input

```
St1
number1
1234

St2
number2
456
```

Sample Output

```
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```

The answer above uses Raku's `lines` routine, which reads input lines lazily and strips newlines by default. Basically with the code above, `lines` are read in, `join`-ed back again with newlines, and split where `\n**2..*` two-or-more  consecutive newlines are found. Then each element is `map`-ped into and remaining single `\n` newlines are translated to commas. Finally the resultant elements are output using Raku's `.put for...` idiom *('put' stands for 'print-using-[newline]-terminator')*.

Again, above is the most robust solution. However you can get a similar result with simpler code, assuming you you don't mind receiving output with terminal "`,`" commas. The code exploits the difference between `print` (no terminal newline) and `put` (adds terminal newline):

```perl
raku -ne 'if .chars { print $_~"," } else { put $_ };'
```

The code above preserves line-spacing where sections are separated by multiple consecutive blank lines (unlike the first answer, which removes all blank lines).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686651/227738
https://docs.raku.org/type/Cool#routine_lines
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

If the consecutive lines to join are **just** 2:

```
sed '/^$/d;N;N;y/\n/,/' test
```

- Remove all the empty lines
- Get the next two lines
- Replace all occurrence of `\n` with an `,`

---

Join all lines, not just two, separed by one or more empty lines:

```bsh
sed '
    /^$/d;:a
    H;N;$!{
    /\n$/!ba
    }
    y/\n/,/
    s/,$//
' test
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks. See if it is ok now.

Comment: Thanks again @StéphaneChazelas !

Answer (score -1):

```
for ((i=1;i<=countoflineinfile;i++)); do  sed -n "$i,$((i+3))p" gh.txt|awk 'ORS=","' ;echo "";i=$((i+3)); done|sed "s/,*$//g"
```

output

```
St1,number1,1234
St2,number2,456
```